# How to generate ddl by comparing json and yaml file data

Tags: json, liquibase, ddl

**similar products**:

liquibase, I am not sure.

**target:**

build an internal API for use by other modules

i hope to define the table information through the web page, I will generate a json description.

like this

```json
{
    "tables": {
        "columns": [
            {
                "key": "field",
                "desc": "the field desc",
                ...other
            }
        ],
        "indexe": ...
        "unique_indexe": ...
        ...other
    },
    ""
}
```

of course, this structure can be changed.

I hope to provide two json or yaml files, and then compare the sql ddl of the difference. Of course, in fact, I can calculate their differences, but I cannot generate the correct sql ddl.

i hope it is one of php, nodejs, golang. Since I am not good at java, I have to give up liquibase.